# Trained Machine Learning model is too big

Tags: python, machine-learning, pickle, random-forest

We have trained an Extra Tree model for some regression task. Our model consists of 3 extra trees, each having 200 trees of depth 30. On top of the 3 extra trees, we use a ridge regression.

We trained our model for several hours and `pickle`d the trained model (the entire class object), for later use. However, the size of saved trained model is too big, about 140 GB!

Is there a way to reduce the size of the saved model? Are there any configuration in `pickle` that could be helpful, or any alternative for `pickle`?

Comment: The scikit model persistence [page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#) suggests that using `joblib` can be more efficient in some cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the best case (binary trees), you will have `3 * 200 * (2^30 - 1) = 644245094400` nodes or `434Gb` assuming each one node would only cost 1 byte to store. I think that 140GB is a pretty decent size in comparision.

Comment: your calculation is assuming the trees are all full?

Comment: Yes, I assumed that the trees are self-balancing trees and the nodes are distributed equally across all depth.

Answer (score 25):

You can try using `joblib` with compression parameter.

```py
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(your_algo, 'pickle_file_name.pkl', compress=3)
```

compress - from 0 to 9. Higher value means more compression, but also slower read and write times. Using a value of 3 is often a good compromise.

You can use python standard compression modules zlib, gzip, bz2, lzma and xz. To use that you can just specify the format with specific extension

Example:

```
joblib.dump(obj, 'your_filename.pkl.z')   # zlib
```

More information, see the [link](http://gael-varoquaux.info/programming/new_low-overhead_persistence_in_joblib_for_big_data.html).