# Best method for serialization or saving Random Forest Classifier model object to use in production environment

Tags: python, serialization, deserialization, pickle, random-forest

I've been training my RF multi-class classifier on around 12 million records. The base model went upto 60 gb when saved though pickle. After fine-tuning the model (the final parameters without much compromising the accuracy and the pickle size) the pickle size went down to 5 gb which is also huge.

I tried many methods of saving the model like pickle, joblib, dill, cpickle, jsonpickle and some compression methods (saving via joblib via compression methods like saving a z or gzip file).
The problem is when I save my model through PICKLE or dill the minimum size I get is 5 gb. Although JOBLIB and the compression methods give me a model size of 1 gb but problem arises when the model file is being loaded back as Randomforest object. The RAM shoots more than 16 gb which gives the memory error.

Any idea how can I solve this? Any better model saving method? I'm working in python and using scikit-learn for RF model.

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/8358/prohibitive-size-of-random-forest-when-saved-to-disk

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591621/trained-machine-learning-model-is-too-big

Comment: Thanks, I've already used these approaches. The problem here is although I reduced my pickle size to 1gb (while saving the forest) but when I load it back for predicting, the RAM shoots upto more than 16 gb which gives memory error. Size is not much problem here but overshooting of RAM while loading the pickle file back is.

Comment: I've already compromised much of accuracy by tweaking model parameters to make the forest lighter and can't make it more shallow as it is having large impact on accuracy.

Comment: Nice! I was actually surprised the size can grow so fast. For me this is where intuition completely is against facts. I feel there is not much of a problem/bug/inefficiency here that can be 'fixed'. More of how to smartly deal with large amounts.

Comment: In case anyone facing a similar issue, here's how I solved this problem:
https://towardsdatascience.com/the-power-of-pickletools-handling-large-model-pickle-files-7f9037b9086b