# sklearn, joblib: Loading large model causes memory error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, joblib

I have trained and saved an `sklearn` `RandomForestClassifier` in the following way:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=4, n_informative=2, n_redundant=0, random_state=0, shuffle=False)
clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0).fit(X, y)

import joblib
joblib.dump(clf, "D:/mymodel.gz", compress=3)
```

The final model (as saved on HDD) is about 6 GB large.

When I try to load the model again using:

```
clf_loaded = joblib.load("D:/mymodel.gz")
pred = clf_loaded.predict(X)
```

I get a memory error even though my available RAM is just under 60 GB.

It seems that `joblib.load()` requires a huge amount of RAM in excess of the original file size (6 GB).

**Q:** What are alternative options to save an `sklearn` model locally and load it again without consuming massive RAM space?

As far as I know, `pickle` will not outperform `joblib` and is per docs [not recommended for sklearn models](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html).

I checked some other questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62985459/loading-large-trained-machine-learning-model-with-joblib), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591621/trained-machine-learning-model-is-too-big), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62255299/best-method-for-serialization-or-saving-random-forest-classifier-model-object-to), and [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/8358/prohibitive-size-of-random-forest-when-saved-to-disk) but could not find a workable solution.

Comment: Since you are using the RandomForestClassifier, you could check the more interoperable ONNX format, which incidentaly happens to have an example in http://onnx.ai/sklearn-onnx/

Comment: Never worked with it, but I will have a look.

Comment: I've experienced something like this too. In my case, I only need a fraction of the data in the joblib, depending on the arguments passed to the program I'm running. It could be as dramatic as 1% of the joblib's contents are relevant -- but as far as I can tell, I have to load it all into memory and _then_ winnow it down. It's too late at that point since the memory is already consumed... I wonder if anyone has any advice for this situation?